# Getting estimated means after multiple imputation using the mitml, nlme & geepack R packages

Tags: r, nlme, emmeans, mi

I'm running multilevel multiple imputation through the package `mitml` (using the `panimpute()` function) and am fitting linear mixed models and marginal models through the packages `nlme` and `geepack` and the `mitml:with()` function.

I can get the estimates, p-values etc for those through the `testEstimates()` function but I'm also looking to get estimated means across my model predictors. I've tried the `emmeans` package, which I normally use for getting estimated means when running `nlme & geepack` without multiple imputation but doing so emmeans tell me "Can't handle an object of class “mitml.result”".

**I'm wondering is there a way to get pooled estimated means from the multiple imputation analyses I've run?**

The data frames I'm analyzing are longitudinal/repeated measures and in long format. In the linear mixed model I want to get the estimated means for a 2x2 interaction effect and in the marginal model I'm trying to get estimated means for the 6 levels of 'time' variable. The outcome in all models is continuous.

Here's my code

```
# mixed model
fml <- Dep + time ~ 1 + (1|id)
imp <- panImpute(data=Data, formula=fml, n.burn=50000, n.iter=5000, m=100, group = "treatment")
summary(imp)
plot(imp, trace="all")
implist <- mitmlComplete(imp, "all", force.list = TRUE)

fit <- with(implist, lme(Dep ~ time*treatment, random = ~ 1|id, method = "ML", na.action = na.exclude, control = list(opt = "optim")))
testEstimates(fit, var.comp = TRUE)
confint.mitml.testEstimates(testEstimates(fit, var.comp = TRUE))

# marginal model
fml <- Dep + time ~ 1 + (1|id)
imp <- panImpute(data=Data, formula=fml, n.burn=50000, n.iter=5000, m=100)
summary(imp)
plot(imp, trace="all")
implist <- mitmlComplete(imp, "all", force.list = TRUE)

fit <- with(implist, geeglm(Dep ~ time, id = id, corstr ="unstructured"))
testEstimates(fit, var.comp = TRUE)
confint.mitml.testEstimates(testEstimates(fit, var.comp = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to get pooled estimated means from the multiple imputation analyses I've run?

This is not a reprex without `Data`, so I can't verify this works for you.  But `emmeans` provides support for `mira-class` (lists of) models in the `mice` package.  So if you fit your model in `with()` using the `mids` rather than `mitml.list` class object, then you can use that to obtain marginal means of your outcome (and any contrasts or pairwise comparisons afterward).

Using example data found [here](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Multi_level/Multi_level_data.html), which uncomfortably loads an external workspace:

```
con <- url("https://www.gerkovink.com/mimp/popular.RData")
load(con)

## imputation

library(mice)

ini <- mice(popNCR, maxit = 0)
meth <- ini$meth
meth[c(3, 5, 6, 7)] <- "norm"

pred <- ini$pred
pred[, "pupil"] <- 0

imp <- mice(popNCR, meth = meth, pred = pred, print = FALSE)


## analysis

library(lme4) # fit multilevel model
mod <- with(imp, lmer(popular ~ sex + (1|class)))

library(emmeans) # obtain pooled estimates of means
(em <- emmeans(mod, specs = ~ sex) )
pairs(em) # test comparison
```